# Does wso2 BPS has class mediator type feature?

Tags: wso2, bpel, wso2-esb

In ESB we have class mediator where you can write your custom logic through java code. Likewise how can i do exactly the same thing in wso2 BPS? If it is done through creating jar file of my custom logic code, then where to put this jar and how to access this jar while creating BPEL Process? A sample would be great help for me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, In BPS you can write custom extension activities. Using extension activity you can execute java code. Please refer this [blog post](http://ddweerasiri.blogspot.com/2012/04/ws-bpel-20-extension-activity.html) for more information.

Comment: i followed the blog as it is given but it is giving me error as: [2013-05-13 14:46:36,262] ERROR {org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.NStateLatch} -  Deployment of process "{http://ode/bpel/unit
-test}ExtensionActivity-21" failed. The process model requires the engine to understand language extensions defined by h
ttp://ode.apache.org/extensions/b4p. No extension bundle has been registered for this namespace.

Comment: seems like you haven't configured bps.xml. First you have to put extension activity jar into $CARBON_HOME/repository/components/lib/ and then configure BPS by editing $CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/bps.xml. Read readme.txt for more information in sample location. https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/denis/org.wso2.carbon.bpel.extension.activity.sample/README.txt